# How to aggregate results in many to many Query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 3 tables in my database:

**Student**:

- id
- name

**Student_Course**:

- student_id
- course_id

**Course**:

- id
- grade

And I want to list all the students and the results of whether they have pass all of the course they have chosen . Assuming that grade <= 'C' is pass.

I tried sql like:

```
SELECT s.*,
IF('C'>=ALL(SELECT c.grade FROM from Course c WHERE c.id=sc.course_id),1,0) as isPass 
FROM Student s LEFT JOIN Student_Course sc on sc.student_id=s.id
```

This sql works, but if now I want a column 'isGood' which means all the grade='A', do I need to execute the subquery again? How can I get both 'isGood' and 'isPass' by executing subquery only once?

Comment: Why is grade in course? Shouldn't that be a property of the student_course?

Comment: I made a mistake...I just want to make a similar situation with what I got ,  I found I can not edit the question , so please ignore the mistake. You can replace grade with 'isStart' , How can I get 'isAllStart' column for a student ? @Arth

Comment: I'd suggest a new question, your query would change if this mistake is fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the grade would be better served in the junction table. Using that, I have created a scenario that might help you solve your question:

**Scenario**

```
create table student (id int, fullname varchar(50));
insert into student values (1, 'john'), (2, 'mary'), (3, 'matt'), (4, 'donald');

create table course (id int, coursename varchar(50));
insert into course values (1, 'math'), (2, 'science'), (3, 'business');

create table student_course (student_id int, course_id int, grade char(1));
insert into student_course values
(1, 1, 'C'), (1, 2, 'C'), (1, 3, 'C'),
(2, 1, 'A'), (2, 2, 'A'), (2, 3, 'A'),
(3, 1, 'A'), (3, 2, 'C'), (3, 3, 'C'),
(4, 1, 'A'), (4, 2, 'C'), (4, 3, 'F');
```

**Query**

```
select s.*, case when all_a_grades.student_id is not null then 'GOOD' else 'MEH' end as grades

from student s 

left join (
    -- find students who got A in all classes
    select student_id, count(distinct ca.id) as aclasses, count(distinct sc.course_id) as allclasses
    from student_course sc
    left join (select id, 'A' as agrade from course) ca 
      on ca.id = sc.course_id and ca.agrade = sc.grade
    group by student_id
    having aclasses = allclasses
) all_a_grades on all_a_grades.student_id = s.id

where not exists (
    -- let's make sure we filter OUT students who have failed
    -- at least one course
    select 1 
    from (
        -- find students who have failed at least one course
        select distinct student_id
        from student_course
        where grade not in ('A', 'B', 'C')
    ) t where t.student_id = s.id
)
```

**Result**

```
| id | fullname | grades | 
| 1  | john     | MEH    | 
| 2  | mary     | GOOD   | 
| 3  | matt     | MEH    |
```